# how to run JMeter tests (no .jmx script) with maven?

Tags: java, jmeter, maven-3

I'm currently trying to create stress tests for an application and I would like to use JMeter for that.
I want to use an install free solution and no jmx script.
I found several jmeter tutorial but each are based else on jmx script or jmeter gui...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "I would like to use JMeter for that <...> an install free solution and no jmx script."
this is an equivalent to saying "I want to use JMeter, but I don't want to use JMeter"

Comment: @Andy Wiesendanger sorry I don't understand the reason of you comment? Is my question not compliant to the forum rules?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible to use [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) and create your test on-the-fly using Java code but it is something which isn't really recommended and supported so you might not have your questions answered if any.

Just in case you need something to start with:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) - Section  `4.3 Creating a New JMeter Test Purely in Java`
- https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/ - simple Maven project you can use as a template

Comment: Thanks @DmitriT you're currently the only one you propose a solution or at least a starting point :)